# How to set `onSubmit` dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, submit, form-submit, onsubmit

Right now I am in a bit of a dilemma because I cannot edit the `onSubmit` of my form, so I will have to set it dynamically. My problem is, I have no idea how to do this without overwriting the value that is already in the `onSubmit`
For example, lets say I have this code:

```
<form name="bob" onSubmit="something-i-cannot-change">

</form>
```

How would I set another function to happen `onSubmit` along with the other function that is already in there? I looked this up and had no luck... Thanks, I really appreciate any help!!!
Note: If this question is a duplicate of anything, then please let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('[name="bob"]')
        .addEventListener('submit',
                          functionThatDoesSomethingAfter);
```

Note the form has to already be in the DOM so put the code at the end of the body tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Ahhh beautiful... I will have to test this in the morning, and will post the result soon! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("<element-id>").setAttribute("onSubmit", "<action>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Save a reference to the existing onSubmit function and then create a new onSubmit function that does what you'd like and then call the original.

```
// jQuery syntax for DOM work
var originalSubmit = $('#bob').onSubmit
$('#bob').onSubmit = function() { do stuff here then call original };
```

Comment: There is nothing in the OP that indicates jQuery is in use.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the help, but I would rather not use Jquery in this, as I am sure it can be done with JavaScript... Thank you for your time though!

Comment: I assumed jQuery, but the two calls can be replaced by document.getElementById('bob')

Comment: useful for jQuery users who find this question; and like @CoreyCole said, it's just a simple switch for JS. +1