# While migrating Struts 1 to Struts 2, the FormTag class in Struts 2 is missing a getOnsubmit method

Tags: struts2, migration, struts-1, struts-tags

I am doing a Struts 1 to Struts 2 migration. We have Struts 1 code that has extended and customised the `org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag`. Did some search and found that the `org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FormTag` is the equivalent in Struts2.

My current Struts 1 code modifies the `onsubmit` variable of the `FormTag` by calling the `setOnsubmit()`, but it does that by first doing a `getOnsubmit()` like below.

```
    if (this.getOnsubmit() == null) {
        this.setOnsubmit(subCmd + subCmdEnd);
    }
    else {
        this.setOnsubmit(subCmd + this.getOnsubmit() + subCmdEnd);
    }
```

The Struts 2 class has the `setOnsubmit()`, but not the `getOnsubmit()`. Do we have any other option available to read the `onsubmit` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<s:form>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/form-tag.html) belongs to Struts 2 core tag library. So, if you need to use your own tag that extends this one then you should extend [`org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FormTag` class](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/ui/FormTag.html) and provide your own implementation by overriding `public` methods, and adding additional methods. The `onsubmit` field has a `protected` modifyer.

But before doing any changes to the Struts 2 framework ask an advice from qualifyed experts: why do you need to do it? For carrying the old  code to the new one? **The code that is written for S1 is incompatible with S2.**

`onsubmit` is a HTML attribute of the HTML `<form>` tag, and it could be set in the any other ways on the server, i.e. using OGNL, or on the client using JavaScript.

Also when migrating from Struts1 to Struts 2 you should read [Struts 1 to Struts 2 migration strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588794/573032).

Comment: Thanks @roman. 
My current Struts 1 code changes the onSubmit such that a JS function is called whenever the form is submitted. 

If I read your answer right, I'll not be able to control this by extending the FormTag and should rather change the onsubmit in the JSP using javascript. I think this might help. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/17128026/11550524]

Let me check. Thanks again